# Python: Reading long lines with asyncio.StreamReader.readline()

Tags: python, asynchronous, io, python-asyncio

The asyncio version of `readline`() (1) allows reading a single line from a stream asynchronously. However, if it encounters a line that is longer than a limit, it will raise an exception (2). It is unclear how to resume reading after such an exception is raised.

I would like a function similar to `readline`(), that simply discards parts of lines that exceed the limit, and continues reading until the stream ends. Does such a method exist? If not, how to write one?

1: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streamreader

2: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/asyncio/streams.py#L549

Comment: Thank you all for the high-quality answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library implementation of `asyncio.StreamReader.readline` is almost what you want.  That function raises a `ValueError` in the event of a buffer overrun, but it first removes a chunk of data from the buffer and discards it.  If you catch the `ValueError` and keep calling `readline`, the stream would keep going.  But you would lose the first chunk of data, which is not what you want.

To achieve what you want you can call a slightly lower-level function `StreamReader.readuntil(separator)`.  If you call `reader.readuntil('\n')` it's equivalent to `reader.readline`.  On an overrun this function raises a `asyncio.LimitOverrunError`, which has an instance variable named `consumed`.  This is an integer representing the current length of the buffer contents.

There are a couple of strange details here.  Despite the variable's name, these bytes have not been "consumed" - they are still in the buffer.  In order to keep the stream going you have to consume them yourself, which you can do by calling the function `StreamReader.readexactly`.  The second strange thing is that the value of `LimitOverrunError.consumed` can be greater than the value of the keyword argument `limit=` that you originally passed to the `open_connection` constructor.  That argument was supposed to set the size of the input buffer but it appears that it merely sets the threshold for raising the `LimitOverrunError`.  Consequently, the buffer might contain the separator already, but fortunately the character count in `LimitOverrunError.consumed` does not include the separator.  So a call to `readexactly` will not consume the separator.

You can achieve exactly what you want by calling readuntil, with added logic to handle LimitOverrunError.  In the exception handler you save the first chunk of data and continue to read from the stream.  When you finally encounter the end of the line you return the first chunk that you saved.

Here is a full working demo program.  To test the code I set limit=512 in asyncio.open_connection.  The server transmits a line that's longer than this followed by some shorter lines.  The client reads each of the lines without any exception being raised.

The function you are asking for is `readline_no_limit`.

```
import asyncio

_PORT = 54242

MY_LIMIT = 512

async def readline_no_limit(reader):
    """ Return a bytes object.  If there has not been a buffer
    overrun the returned value will end with include the line terminator,
    otherwise not.

    The length of the returned value may be greater than the limit
    specified in the original call to open_connection."""

    discard = False
    first_chunk = b''
    while True:
        try:
            chunk = await reader.readuntil(b'\n') 
            if not discard:
                return chunk
            break
        except asyncio.LimitOverrunError as e:
            print(f"Overrun detected, buffer length now={e.consumed}")
            chunk = await reader.readexactly(e.consumed)
            if not discard:
                first_chunk = chunk
            discard = True
    return first_chunk

async def client():
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host='localhost', 
        port=_PORT, limit=MY_LIMIT)
    writer.write(b"Hello\n")
    while True:
        line = await readline_no_limit(reader)
        print(f"Received {len(line)} bytes, first 40: {line[:40]}")
        if line == b"End\n":
            break
    writer.write(b"Quit\n")

async def got_cnx(reader, writer):
    while True:
        msg = await reader.readline()
        if msg == b"Quit\n":
            break
        if msg != b"Hello\n":
            continue
        long_line = ' '.join([format(x, "x") for x in range(1000)])
        writer.write(bytes(long_line, encoding='utf8'))
        writer.write(b"\n")
        writer.write(b"Short line\n")
        writer.write(b"End\n")

async def main():
    def shutdown(_future):
        print("\nClient quit, server shutdown")
        server.close()
    client_task = asyncio.create_task(client())
    server = await asyncio.start_server(got_cnx, host='localhost', port=_PORT,
        start_serving = False)
    client_task.add_done_callback(shutdown)
    try:
        await server.serve_forever()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("Server closed normally")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
Overrun detected, buffer length now=3727
Received 3727 bytes, first 40: b'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f 10 11 12'
Received 11 bytes, first 40: b'Short line\n'
Received 4 bytes, first 40: b'End\n'

Client quit, server shutdown
Server closed normally
```

Python 3.11, Ubuntu

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot! I would just rename "readline_no_limit" to "safe_readline", or something along these lines.

Answer (score 1):

In the `asyncio.open_connection()` code there is this comment: *"If you want to customize the StreamReader ... just copy the code ..."*.

---

OK. Let's try. Copied and changed the `StreamReader` line:

```
import asyncio

_DEFAULT_LIMIT = 2 ** 16  # 64 KiB

async def open_trunc_connection(
        host=None, port=None, *, limit=_DEFAULT_LIMIT, **kwds):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    reader = TruncatingStreamReader(limit=limit, loop=loop) # <-- own reader
    protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader, loop=loop)
    transport, _ = await loop.create_connection(
        lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)
    writer = asyncio.StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader, loop)
    return reader, writer
```

---

Now the reader. The higher level first just for the discussion.
Variable `line` is the read line possibly truncated. The
`drain` boolean flag means a rest of a long line still exists and needs to be consumed.

This simple code has a drawback that a truncated line is not returned immediately, but only when the whole line is read up to the newline. If this is not desired, store the flag to `self._drain` (needs to be initialized in `__init__`) and do the "drain" on the next call.

```
class TruncatingStreamReader(asyncio.StreamReader):

    async def readline(self):
        line, drain = await self._truncating_readline()
        while drain:
            discard, drain = await self._truncating_readline()
        return line
```

---

The low level. Based on the standard asyncio code. See coments there if need be. I marked a section below with the comment "we have actually the whole line". This is the case when the line is in the buffer, but happens to be longer than the limit. You could return it untruncated, but it violates the length limit contract.

```
    async def _truncating_readline(self):
        sep = b'\n'
        seplen = len(sep) # i.e. 1
        try:
            line = await self.readuntil(sep)
            return (line, False)
        except asyncio.IncompleteReadError as e:
            line = e.partial
            return (line, False)
        except asyncio.LimitOverrunError as e:
            if self._buffer.startswith(sep, e.consumed):
                # we have actually the whole line ...
                line = bytes(self._buffer[:self._limit])
                del self._buffer[:e.consumed + seplen]
                self._maybe_resume_transport()
                return (line, False)
            line = bytes(self._buffer[:self._limit])
            self._buffer.clear()
            self._maybe_resume_transport()
            return (line, True)
```

---

A test program:

```
async def test():
    r, w = await open_trunc_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', '54321', limit=10)
    async for line in r:
        print(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(test())
```

I made a test "server" with this linux command: `ncat -l 54321 < file.txt`. Must be restarted for each connection.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading a line, you can read some bytes and make a line out of it yourself. I'm going to explain the sync version as it's basically the same thing.

So you don't care about the whole line if it's too big and you want to ignore the rest of the line and go to read the next line. You can use `.read(n)` instead inside a loop and pass a number of bytes you want to read(It's the maximum limit of the line length), it will read *up to* that number of bytes. When you receive bytes, you can use `.find()` method to search for the separator(`\n` in the case of new lines).

Now here is the algorithm:

- if you find your separator, it means the line is shorter than your specified limit. So read the bytes until the separator, yield the line and clear it from the buffer. What stored after separator is the content of your next line! You should pass `n - m` to `.read()` in which `m` is the number of bytes remained in the buffer.
- if you don't find the separator, it means the line is too big. You should read the buffer, yield it and clear it from the buffer. But this time remember that what comes next, is actually part of the current line so you should ignore them until you find the separator again.

```py
from io import BufferedReader


def read_first_part_of_lines(f: BufferedReader, *, limit: int = 10, sep: bytes = b"\n"):
    buffer = bytearray()
    should_ignore = False
    offset = 0

    while True:
        data = f.read(limit - offset)
        if not data:
            return  # you read until the end.
        buffer.extend(data)
        idx = buffer.find(sep)
        if idx != -1:  # sep is found
            if should_ignore:
                del buffer[: idx + 1]
                offset = limit - idx - 1
                should_ignore = False
            else:
                line = buffer[:idx]
                yield bytes(line)
                del buffer[: idx + 1]
                offset = limit - idx - 1
        else:  # sep is not found
            if should_ignore:
                buffer.clear()
                offset = 0
            else:
                line = bytes(buffer)
                yield line
                buffer.clear()
                offset = 0
                should_ignore = True


with open("filename.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in read_first_part_of_lines(f, limit=10, sep=b"\n"):
        print(line)
```

if you have a file(or any stream of data) like:

```
sbjrhc
weynrc874yrb7d83x8dyweyncrb874byr43xn8
kjahbksjfdlmcxnvnsdif643675t4dsbvbndsfbdshfb
sdlkjn
lsdfjndaslu48r
```

this would be the output:

```
b'sbjrhc'
b'weynrc874y'
b'kjahbksjfd'
b'sdlkjn'
b'lsdfjndasl'
```

Of course the bigger you specify the `n`, the faster you get lines. It just uses more memory. The point is, it's now under your control.

The above was the sync version. You can apply the same logic with your async case. The pseudo code would be:

```py
from asyncio import StreamReader

async def read_first_part_of_lines(
    reader: StreamReader, *, limit: int = 10, sep: bytes = b"\n"
):
    buffer = bytearray()
    should_ignore = False
    offset = 0

    while True:
        data = await reader.read(limit - offset)
        if not data:
            return  # you read until the end.
        buffer.extend(data)
        ....

async def main():
    ...
    reader = ...
    async for line in read_first_part_of_lines(reader, limit=10, sep=b"\n"):
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's always hairy mixing threading and asyncio, but I'd still be tempted to work around this by doing so - fundamentally line reading tends to smell like blocking io

```py
import asyncio
import queue
from io import TextIOWrapper
from threading import Thread

async def truncating_line_reader(stream, max_line_length=1024):
    """ an asynchronous, truncating line reader

        > a function similar to readline(), that simply discards parts of lines
        > that exceed the limit, and continues reading until the stream ends

        internally this works by passing off reads to an internal thread
        while relying on queue.Queue for synchronization
    """

    def line_reader_inner(
        stream,
        output_queue,
        max_line=1024,            # somewhat arbitrarily chosen
        blocksize_discard=65535,  # somewhat arbitrarily chosen
        newline_when_truncate=True,
    ):
        stream = TextIOWrapper(stream)
        while True:  # loop inner
            line = stream.readline(max_line)
            if line.endswith("\n"):
                output_queue.put(line)
                continue
            if newline_when_truncate:  # disguise truncated lines
                line = line + "\n"  # or line[:-1] + "\n", but len hints
            output_queue.put(line)

            # now read and discard in chunks to avoid reading forever
            data = ""
            while not data.endswith("\n"):
                data = line.readline(blocksize_discard)


    q = queue.Queue(1024)  # arbitrary as reader blocks internally

    # thread creation is probably nonblocking?..
    t = Thread(
        target=line_reader_inner,
        args=(stream, q, max_line_length),
        daemon=True,
    )
    t.start()

    while True:
        try:
            yield q.get_nowait()    # don't block loop
        except queue.Empty:
            await asyncio.sleep(0)  # let other tasks preempt
```

some caveats

- only lightly tested
- inspired by this venerable answer to [A non-blocking read on a subprocess.PIPE in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4896288/4541045)
- lengths of reads are in characters, not necessarily bytes